# How to perform ImageMagick gradient call with python wand

Tags: python-2.7, imagemagick, wand

Trying to convert this ImageMagick command to Python Wand code but I don't see a means to create a gradient image with Wand.

```
    convert -size 800x800 gradient:"rgba(0,0,0,0.12)-rgba(0,0,0,1)" gradient_overlay.png

    convert gradient_overlay.png background.png -compose Overlay -composite -depth 8 background_gradient.png
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this with wand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it based fmw42 feedback

```
with Color('black') as blackColor:
with Image(width=800, height=800, background=blackColor) as black:
    blackPath = existing[:existing.rfind('/') + 1] + 'black.png'
    with Color('white') as whiteColor:
        with Image(width=800, height=800, background=whiteColor) as alpha:
            fxFilter = "(j*(1-0.12)/(h-1)+0.12)"
            with alpha.fx(fxFilter) as filteredImage:
                black.composite_channel('default_channels', filteredImage, 'copy_opacity', 0, 0)
                black.save(filename=blackPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to allocate an instance of wand, set canvas size, then read the pseudo-image format.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

with Image() as canvas:
    library.MagickSetSize(canvas.wand, 800, 800)
    canvas.read(filename="gradient:rgba(0,0,0,0.12)-rgba(0,0,0,1)")
    canvas.save(filename="gradient_overlay.png")
```

[image: gradient_overlay.png]

Answer (score 1):

**ImageMagick Equivalent For Use With Wand**

I have not used Wand, but I can show you how to do it by reference to ImageMagick. You can create a new transparent image. Then use the fx operator to modify the alpha channel into a gradient.

The equivalent Wand references are:

Create a new transparent image (the default) - see http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/read.html?highlight=new%20image#open-empty-image

Use fx to convert the alpha channel to a gradient - see http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html

```
convert -size 800x800 xc:transparent -channel a -fx "(j*(1-0.12)/(h-1)+0.12)" +channel alpha.png
```

[image]

Here is how I got the fx formula:

You want a 12% gray at the top (0.12) and 100% gray/white at the bottom (1.0). So we take the formula:

```
c = a*j + b

At j=0 the top, you need 0.12, so

0.12 = a*0 + b -->  b = 0.12

At j=(h-1) the bottom, you want 1, so 

1 = a*(h-1) + 0.12 --> a = (1-0.12)/(h-1)

So the equation is:

c = j*(1-0.12)/(h-1) + 0.12
```

h is the height of the image (800).

Comment: Thank you for explanation with your suggesting I was able to solve the problem.

Comment: You might post back your Wand code, so others could benefit from it.

Comment: Provided it below.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. But the code in my answer above might provide you a shorter more direct method in Wand.